# magento2.1 bottom pagination when there is no page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-listing, list.phtml

When i set pagination to 60 and i have 55 items, so shows 55 items and it is nice, but still shows a bar of pagination on the bottom of the page. how can i remove it when there is no pagination page number?

[image: with pagination]

[image: without pagination]

Comment: can you add the screen of this issue?

Comment: It seems that you are using a custom theme.

Comment: yes i am, but need to remove it at this situation

Comment: @PMPD, try to print the number product in your collection if its upto 60 then its fine otherwise you have issue with your collection.